# Pytorch vs. Keras: Pytorch model overfits heavily

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

For several days now, I'm trying to replicate my keras training results with pytorch. Whatever I do, the pytorch model will overfit far earlier and stronger to the validation set then in keras. For pytorch I use the same XCeption Code from https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch.

The dataloading, the augmentation, the validation, the training schedule etc. are equivalent. Am I missing something obvious? There must be a general problem somewhere. I tried thousands of different module constellations, but nothing seems to come even close to the keras training. Can somebody help?

Keras model: val accuracy > 90%

```
# base model
base_model = applications.Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

# top model
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# Compile model
from keras import optimizers
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

# LROnPlateau etc. with equivalent settings as pytorch
```

Pytorch model: val accuracy ~81%

```
from xception import xception
import torch.nn.functional as F

# modified from https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch
class XCeption(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(XCeption, self).__init__()

        original_model = xception(pretrained="imagenet")

        self.features=nn.Sequential(*list(original_model.children())[:-1])
        self.last_linear = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Linear(original_model.last_linear.in_features, 512),
             nn.ReLU(),
             nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
             nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        )

    def logits(self, features):
        x = F.relu(features)
        x = F.adaptive_max_pool2d(x, (1, 1))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.last_linear(x)
        return x

    def forward(self, input):
        x = self.features(input)
        x = self.logits(x)
        return x 

device = torch.device("cuda")
model=XCeption(len(class_names))
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    # dim = 0 [30, xxx] -> [10, ...], [10, ...], [10, ...] on 3 GPUs
    model = nn.DataParallel(model)
model.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(size_average=False)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
scheduler = lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', factor=0.2, patience=5, cooldown=5)
```

Thank you very much!

Update: 
Settings:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
scheduler = lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', factor=0.2, patience=5, cooldown=5)

model = train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, 
                        criterion, optimizer, scheduler, 
                        batch_size, trainmult=8, valmult=10, 
                        num_epochs=200, epochs_top=0)
```

Cleaned training function:

```
def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, batch_size, trainmult=1, valmult=1, num_epochs=None, epochs_top=0):
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):                        
    for phase in ['train', 'val']:
        running_loss = 0.0
        running_acc = 0
        total = 0
        # Iterate over data.
        if phase=="train":
            model.train(True)  # Set model to training mode
            for i in range(trainmult):
                for data in train_loader:
                    # get the inputs
                    inputs, labels = data
                    inputs, labels = inputs.to(torch.device("cuda")), labels.to(torch.device("cuda"))
                    # zero the parameter gradients
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    # forward
                    outputs = model(inputs) # notinception
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()
                    # statistics                      
                    total += labels.size(0)
                    running_loss += loss.item()*labels.size(0)
                    running_acc += torch.sum(preds == labels)
                    train_loss=(running_loss/total)
                    train_acc=(running_acc.double()/total)
        else:
            model.train(False)  # Set model to evaluate mode
            with torch.no_grad():
                for i in range(valmult):
                    for data in val_loader:
                        # get the inputs
                        inputs, labels = data
                        inputs, labels = inputs.to(torch.device("cuda")), labels.to(torch.device("cuda"))
                        # zero the parameter gradients
                        optimizer.zero_grad()
                        # forward
                        outputs = model(inputs)
                        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                        loss = criterion(outputs, labels.data)
                        # statistics
                        total += labels.size(0)
                        running_loss += loss.item()*labels.size(0)
                        running_acc += torch.sum(preds == labels)
                        val_loss=(running_loss/total)
                        val_acc=(running_acc.double()/total)  
            scheduler.step(val_loss)
    return model
```

Comment: This is just a guess. Have checked the init methods? I'm not sure what init is used in keras, but with default init method, the values for weights in pytorch can grow quite large - this could result in faster learning.
Can you check the difference in the training acc?

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I get your question right. Both models should be initialized with the pretrained Imagenet weights. The intialization per layer should be the same. The model is benchmarked on imagenet and scores comparably in pytorch and keras. 
The training acc is very good in both keras and pytorch. Fitting itself, should be fine. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, seems like I did not go carefully enough through your question.
Then I have no idea - I never used imagenet models. But you do additional training on the pre-trained models? (If so, did you try using more or less epochs then for the keras model)

Comment: Yes. I use the same training schedule. The Keras model achieves its top val_acc around epoch 30, the pytorch models val loss/acc stagnates around epoch 5. It is really strange.

Comment: Sorry, I have not idea so far. Something has to be completely off there with that big difference in acc. I suggest adding the information with the epochs to the question. 
You might consider also checking or posting the lines which are responsible for the actual training.

Comment: In the meantime I replicated the preprocessing procedure from keras, which now should be the SAME. For reasons unknown to me that boosted the val_acc to ~81%. While updating my training code: Could it be, that model.train(False) is a problem in the validation? Do I need model.eval() instead?

Comment: Are you using any LR scheduler in Keras? I see that you use Plateau in PyTorch.

Comment: Can you please plot train/test accuracy vs epoch and learning rate vs epoch for Keras and PyTorch, so we can see where the problem is?

Comment: There exist variations on dropout in pytorch i.e Dropout VS Dropout2d. Dropout 2D drops entire channels of images while Dropout specific pixels. Is it possible this is the problem? Perhaps the pytorch data loader isn't shuffling the training batches while the keras data loader does?

Comment: I have only seen model.eval() before, not mode.train(False). Also, Kevinj22's got a good point, are you passing shuffle=True in your trainloader?

Comment: You have accidentally unindented an else block....tho prob doesnt explain the results.

Comment: I know, this is a bit off topic, but may I ask, why you want to switch from `keras` to `pytorch`?

Comment: I think the default settings of ADAM vary between Keras and PyTorch!

Comment: If you do not train either model, do you get the same loss during validation? Different losses would suggest different architectures and that the problem is not related to training.

Answer (score 2):

it may be because type of weight initialization you are using 
otherwise this should not happen
try with same initializer in both the models

Answer (score 1):

```py
self.features=nn.Sequential(*list(original_model.children())[:-1])
```

Are you sure that this line re-instantiates your model in exactly the same way? You're using a NN.Sequential instead of the original XCeption model's forward function. If there's anything in that forward function that isn't the exact same as using a nn.Sequential, it will not reproduce the same performance.

Instead of wrapping it in a Sequential, you could just change this

```py
my_model = Xception()
# load weights before you change the architecture
my_model = load_weights(path_to_weights)
# overwrite the original's last_linear with your own
my_model.last_linear = nn.Sequential(
             nn.Linear(original_model.last_linear.in_features, 512),
             nn.ReLU(),
             nn.Dropout(p=0.5),
             nn.Linear(512, num_classes)
        )
```